# Получение информации по "кусочкам"

Tags: ajax, javascript

В server-side языках программирования есть функции ответа, вроде println(), echo() и т.д. Насколько я понимаю, после выполнения этой функции сразу отдастся ответ, даже если потом встретятся ещё println()ы в коде. То есть получается, каждый println() отдаёт свой кусок информации. При стандартном использовании xmlHttpRequest просто будет ждаться все куски, после чего отдастся полный response. **А как можно получить кусок, и сразу же обработать его?** *Ну то есть отловить какое-нибудь событие (onНовыйКусок) и получить его.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать WebSocket или Long Polling для старых браузеров:

1. NodeJS — [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) ([rus](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/)), [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) и т.п.
2. [NGiNX_HTTP_Push_Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) ([rus](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2010/07/21/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC-nginx-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-long-polling-comet-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80/))
3. [Realplexor](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79189/) — PHP
4. И много, много других по запросу "[Comet server](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Comet+server&oq=Comet+server&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.272j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)"

P.S. Также некоторые браузеры поддердживаю `xhr.onprogress = function (){ alert(xhr.responseText); }`

Comment: Да тут проблема сделать это на клиенте

Comment: Что значит "на клиенте"? Вы хотите получать ответ от сервера "кусками", это можно сделать только организовав polling или подняв Comet sever, либо [Server-Sent Events][1]

P.S. Также некоторые браузеры поддердживаю `xhr.onprogress = function (){ alert(xhr.responseText); }`

 [1]: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: @RubaXa onprogress то что надо

Answer (score 0):

echo(), кстати, не функция, а конструкция. Может, воспользоваться промежуточным серверным скриптом, который будет сохранять результаты получения в файл, а уже на Ajax к нему обращаться?

Comment: Ещё chunked-encoding посмотрите, если интересно